# Simplest way to download text from URL

Tags: android

Is there a simplest way to download small text string from URL like this one:"http://app.georeach.com/ios/version.txt"
In iOS its pretty simple. But for android em not finding something good. what is the method for getting text like that from the above URL??

I used this code in onCreate of hello app,n app crashed:

```
try {
        // Create a URL for the desired page
        URL url = new URL("http://app.georeach.com/ios/version.txt");

        // Read all the text returned by the server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String str;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(str);
            // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
        }
        in.close();
        tv.setText(sb.toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        tv.setText("mal");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        tv.setText("io");
    }
```

Comment: I see the way you implemented a pretty easy one. Not sure there's another easier than that.

Comment: (1) Include stack trace from your logcat. (2) _Never_ do any network communication on the main thread.

Comment: add 'catch( Exception e) { tv.setText( e.getMessage());}'

Comment: There is no such simple way as on iOS, where you just have to init a String from an URL, but that should be considered a good thing. The iOS version blocks the UI thread.

Comment: @FD_ : `EntityUtils.toString(new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet("<url here>"))
        .getEntity())` Simple enough for me

Comment: Further, I believe the newer versions of Android will not allow you to do network communication on the main thread - you _must_ use another thread (AsyncTask is the easiest).  This may be the reason why it crashes.

Comment: @AleksG I bet you are right. This is the reason for the crash.

Comment: @njzk2 Yeah, but run that on the UI thread and there goes your user experience.

Comment: nothing prevents you from putting this in a simple asynctask

Comment: yeah AsyncTask worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a new class extended from AsyncTask. You can't do network stuff in the main thread. It could work but you may not want to do that. Take a look at this link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Also don't forget to add Internet permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://bla-bla...");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}

// your text is here
String text = sb.toString()
```

Do not forget to catch and handle `IOException` and close all streams.

Answer (score 0):

An "easier" way would be this:

```
String url2txt = null;
try {
  // Being address an URL instance
  url2txt = new Scanner(address.openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
} catch (IOException e) { ... }
```

The thing is what you consider "easier". As far as code goes, probably this is the shortest way, but it depends on what you want to do afterwards with the obtained text.